# Enabling remote debugging in application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, remote-debugging

I use remote debugging in visual studio 2012 by using `msvsmon.exe` on the remote pc, but is there a way to merge this in the setup of the application so I dont have to add the folder to the remote pc and run the app and change the options. Now I know that I can embed it in the installer and run it from my application, but how do I set the options from my application, like the `Autehentication mode`.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What options exactly do you want to set and how? MSVSMON has a bunch of command line options. Just run "msvsmon /?" and you will get a help page describing all of them. You can select the authentication mode by using that as well.